# class std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >' has no member named 'second'

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<set>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

class DS{
    vector<pair<int,int>> *l;
public:

    DS(int n){
        l = new vector<pair<int, int>>;
    }

    create_disjointSubset(int n){
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        l->push_back({i,NULL});
      }
    }

    int find(int curr){
        if(l[curr].second == NULL){
            return curr;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

That's the code.
I am just trying to create a class called DS (disjoint subsets), and I am also trying to create a vector of pairs to store two integer values. I am new to c++ and I don't know for sure what may be wrong with the code. The error, by the way, is in the function **find**, for some reason I cannot use **l[curr].second** or even **l[curr].first**. I would appreacite any hints or answers

Comment: you have to deref the pointer that is `l`

Comment: `vector<pair<int,int>> *l;` + the constructor are nonsense and are pains. Avoid using  pointers: `vector<pair<int,int>> l;`.

Comment: A `vector` is basically a smart pointer to a dynamic buffer.  Having a pointer to a vector is just plain odd.

Comment: `l[cur]` doesn't work because `l` is a pointer, so the compiler thinks `l` points to the first element of an array of vectors, and you want the `cur`th vector. Just use `vector<pair<int,int>> l;` and remove the `new`. There is almost never a reason to dynamically allocate a `std::vector`. Overusing `new` is a common mistake for new developers, specially those coming into C++ with a background in object oriented languages like Java or C#.

Comment: In general, [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it explained a lot, and it is working fine now:) thank youu:)

Comment: One last tip: lower-case **L** (***`l`***) is not a good choice as an identifier; it can simply be mistaken with numeric literal **one** (***`1`***).